# TinyButStrong created dynamic <th> with dynamic <tr> and <td> looping issue

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, tinybutstrong

I want to create the leave report of employee in calender table view as attached image.

[image]

i have fetched employee from controller and stored in and array.
same way i am fetching the dates(based on selected year and month) in controller and stored in an array.
based on this employee and date, i am fetching the leaves of each employee and stored in an array.

**controller**

```
    $month = 7;
    $year = 2015;
            for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)//for dynamic dates as displayed in image
            {
                $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
                if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
                $this->data['blk4'][]['date']=date('d', $time);
                $this->data['blk5'][]['day']=date('D', $time);
                $this->data['blk6'][]['fulldates']=date('Y-m-d',$time);
            }
            $data['employee'] = $this->teamprofile_model->allTeamMembers('team_profile_full_name', 'ASC');//fetching all amployee

            foreach($data['employee'] as $d)//for each employee checking the leave
            {
                foreach($this->data['blk6'] as $date)//for each date
                {   
                    $this->db->where('employee_id',$d['team_profile_id']);
                    $this->db->where('leave_date',$date['dates']);
                    $Q=$this->db->get('leave_reports');
                    if($Q->num_rows() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row)
                        {
                            $data1[] = $row;
                        }
                    }
                    $this->data['blk8'][]['leave'] = $data1[0]['leave_time'];//stored leave of each employee in this array
                    $data1="";
                }
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="footable table table-bordered table-hover" border="1">
      <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Employee</th>//display employee
                 <th><!--[blk4.date;block=th;comm]--><br/><!--[blk5.day;block=th;comm]--></th> //display dates as displying in above image
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody class="">
            <tr>
                <td><!--[blk7.all_team_members;block=tr;comm]--></td>//dynamic employee list
                <td>here i want to display the leave stored in [blk8.leave]</td>                     
            </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

but the problem is that the [blk8.leave] stored all employees leave of each dates so if i print it as [blk8.leave;block=td;comm] then it print all array value in one row. I want to break this array after month's end date that is 31.

[image]

**output should be :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Leave data is structured linearly while it need to be associated with a date.

TBS (TinyButStrong) as a built in feature for merging tables with dynamics columns (or other similar structure).

The example under is very similar to your problem, you can adapt it easily.
http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=dyncol1

But the structure of your data should be amended.
Here is an example of how the data could be:

```
        $blk7 = array();
        foreach($data['employee'] as $d)//for each employee checking the leave
        {
            $employee = array(
                'team_profile_id' => $d['team_profile_id'],
                'all_team_members' => $d['all_team_members'],
            );
            foreach($this->data['blk6'] as $date)//for each date
            {   
                $this->db->where('employee_id',$d['team_profile_id']);
                $this->db->where('leave_date',$date['dates']);
                $Q=$this->db->get('leave_reports');
                if($Q->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row)
                    {
                        $data1[] = $row;
                    }
                }
                $column = 'leave_' . $date['dates'];
                $employee[$column] = $data1[0]['leave_time'];//stored leave of each employee in this array
                $data1="";
            }
            $blk7[] = $employee;
        }
```

Comment: Hey thanks bro thank you very much. But i have one doubt that what will be the HTML code ? <td>here i want to display the leave hours store in $blk7</td>

Comment: I have made one little change in controller that i have stored $employee in  **$this->data['blk7'][]['leave']=$employee;** and in HTML i have write **<!--[blk7.leave.all_team_members;block=tr;comm]-->** to display employee name and its works. but the leave_date is dynamic element of an array so how to write leave hours in HTML page.

Comment: Hey i have done. i write **<!--[blk7.leave.leavetime_[blk6.dates;block=td;];block=td;comm]-->** in html in place of leave hours. Thanks again bro :)